# How to use sed to find the corresponding place in a text file and update it shell

Tags: shell, replace, sed

```
Book name:author:price:Qty:Qty Sold
==================================
harry potter:james:12.99:197:101
===============================
```

I want to update the QTY which is the value of 197 in this case but i cant seems to be able to update the value with my program please help me as i have just started learning shell programming. Thanks

```
function update_qty_available
{
grep -c "$title:$author" BookDB.txt > /dev/null # Look for a line with matching values

if [ $? == 0 ]; 
then # If found then offer to change Qty
echo "Update Qty to what?"
read newQty
sed -i "s/\($title:$author\):[^:]:[^:]*:/\1:$newQty/" BookDB.txt
    echo "Book's Qty has been updated successfully!"
fi
```

Comment: You should consider using awk. Or an actual database. *(Or an actual programming language.)*

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams its a part of my assignment , i manage to update the price but i cant seem to be able to update the QTY.

Comment: Once you're done with this busywork, learn how to do it in awk.

Comment: I thought J.K.Rowling wrote the Harry Potter books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactored to use `grep -q`; fix the `if` idiom; anchor the search to start of line; use `read -p` instead of a separate `echo`; capture the price inside the parens so that it's not lost; add the missing repeat in the regex; and add back the separator colon after the new qty value; also, add an `else` clause so that the function doesn't fail silently.

```
function update_qty_available
{
    if grep -q "^$title:$author:" BookDB.txt
    then
        read -p "Update Qty to what?" newQty
        sed -i "s/^\($title:$author:[^:]*\):[^:]*:/\1:$newQty:/" BookDB.txt
        echo "Book's Qty has been updated successfully!"
    else
        echo "$0: BookDB.Txt: no '$title' by '$author'" >&2
    fi
}
```

Comment: hi , the code u gave me works but the newQty sort of replace the price too anyway to get around that?

Comment: I fixed that in an edit already, and a couple of other issues, too.

Comment: can u explain this line to me?  sed -i "s/^\($title:$author:[^:]*\):[^:]*:/\1:$newQty:/" BookDB.txt

Comment: Huh? It's pretty much copied verbatim (modulo some small fixes) from your original script.  If you have a new question, my suggestion would be to post a new question instead of following up here, where basically only you and I will see it.

Comment: @tripleeee i mean what if i decided to update the title of the book when in that line should i edit?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an asterisk after the first character class. And don't forget to expand the group.

Comment: Cryptic, but accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you'd do with `awk`:

#### Content of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=":"
    printf "Enter the book's name: "
    getline name < "-"
    printf "Enter author's name: "
    getline author < "-"
    printf "Enter new quantity: "
    getline newQty < "-"
}

$1==name && $2==author { $4=newQty }1
```

#### Run:

```
$ cat BookDB.txt 
Book name:author:price:Qty:Qty Sold
==================================
harry potter:james:12.99:197:101
===============================
```

```
$ awk -f script.awk BookDB.txt 
Enter the book's name: harry potter
Enter author's name: james
Enter new quantity: 5000
Book name:author:price:Qty:Qty Sold
==================================
harry potter:james:12.99:5000:101
===============================
```