# Search book by title/author

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

Hi i am new to shell programming i hope u can guide me along thanks.

Hi i need a function to search either book title or author from a .txt file and echo out the following

```
Title:*Enter*
Author:Scissorhands
```

Found 3 records : 
C++ for dummies, John Scissorhands, $15.01, 10, 5 
Java for dummies, Mary Scissorhands, $16.02, 20, 15 
VB.NET for dummies, Edward Scissorhands, $17.03, 30, 25

eg

```
Found 3 records : 
C++ for dummies, John Scissorhands, $15.01, 10, 5 
Java for dummies, Mary Scissorhands, $16.02, 20, 15 
VB.NET for dummies, Edward Scissorhands, $17.03, 30, 25
```

my file format is as below

**Book name:author:price:Qty:Qty Sold**

**harry potter:james:12.99:197:101**

```
function Search_book
{
 FILE="/home/student/Downloads/BookDB.txt"
 echo found 1 records : $FILE contents
 cat FILE
}
```

Comment: Didn't @triplee tell you in your [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849131/how-to-use-sed-to-find-the-corresponding-place-in-a-text-file-and-update-it-shel) post that J.K.Rowling wrote the Harry Potter books.

Comment: It is just an example lol , how can i show the book in that format?Star wars VI - return of the jedi, obi-Wan kenobi,$15.98,20,15, if the format in my .txt is harry potter:james:12.99:197:101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Updated mixed [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)/[perl](/questions/tagged/perl) solution:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter search term: " search
perl -ne '
    BEGIN{ $pattern = $ARGV[0]; shift; $n=0 }
    @a=split /:/;
    if ($a[0] =~ m/$pattern/i or $a[1] =~ m/$pattern/i) {
      print "$a[0], $a[1],\$$a[2],$a[3],$a[4]\n";
      $n += 1;
    }
    END{ print "Found $n title(s).\n" }
  ' "$search" /home/student/Downloads/BookDB.txt
```

Output:

```
$ ./search.sh
Enter search term: star wars vi
Title: Star wars VI - return of the jedi
Found 1 title(s).
```

Not that you need regular expressions for wildcards (i.e. `.` instead of `?`, `.*` instead of `*`, etc.), and you don't need to put wildcards at beginning/end of the search term to find matches anywhere in a given (sub)string.

Of course you could also do this entirely in Perl, without the shell script wrapper:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $booklist = './books.txt';
my @book;

print "Enter search term: ";
chomp (my $pattern = <>);

open BOOKS, "<$booklist" or die $!;

my $n = 0;
foreach (<BOOKS>) {
  chomp;
  @book = split /:/;
  if ($book[0] =~ m/$pattern/i or $book[1] =~ m/$pattern/i) {
    print "$book[0], $book[1],\$$book[2],$book[3],$book[4]\n";
    $n += 1;
  }
}

close BOOKS;

print "Found $n title(s).\n";
```

---

For an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution see [Adrian Frühwirth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17854361/1630171).

Comment: Hi , i will like to prompt user for either Book title or Author so that the code can search for the relevant book in the system , is there a way to ask for user input for book title and author rather than using "Star Wars VI"?

Comment: thanks but i will like to include the author , price , qty and qty left in , similar to my above desired output

Comment: if i want to skip using book title and instead use author as a variable to find books how should i change the code? Thanks u so much u have been a great help =D

Comment: No need to change the code. It's already looking at both title and author field.

Comment: what i am trying to say is , if the user decide to put the title empty and just wanna search the author and making the code just pull out the relevant author names like my eg output on top , the program will request user to type in 2 input , 1 is title and the other is author , can u help me out with this? Sorry to bother u so much thanks !

Comment: That'd be a significant enough change to warrant another question. But why would you want to split this up? Do you get that much title matches when looking for a particular author? If not, I'd rather keep the UI simple.

Comment: i will like the user to input title or author as to pull out data its like a book keeping system used in library. can i have your contact such as im or facebook so we can discuss further? sorry i am a newcomer in this language and its killing me.

Answer (score 1):

```
search_book()
{
    awk -F':' -v search="$1" '$1 ~ search || $2 ~ search { i++; printf "%s, %s,$%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 } END { printf "%d records found\n", i }' books.txt
}
```

_

```
$ cat books.txt
X never marks the spot:Indiana Jones:9.99:1:1
A fistful of barnacles:Captain Twiddlymore:9.99:2:1
The time I blew up LeChuck:Guybrush Threepwood:8.99:100:60
When I blew up LeChuck:Guybrush Threepwood:8.99:100:50
Where I blew up LeChuck:Guybrush Threepwood:8.99:100:2
```

_

```
$ search_book Indiana
X never marks the spot, Indiana Jones,$9.99,1,1
1 records found

$ search_book Guybrush
The time I blew up LeChuck, Guybrush Threepwood,$8.99,100,60
When I blew up LeChuck, Guybrush Threepwood,$8.99,100,50
Where I blew up LeChuck, Guybrush Threepwood,$8.99,100,2
3 records found

$ search_book barnacle
A fistful of barnacles, Captain Twiddlymore,$9.99,2,1
1 records found

$ search_book foo
0 records found
```

Answer (score 0):

@ Wilson Turners last point on Adrian's post:

```
./book.sh 
Enter search term: barnacle
A fistful of barnacles, Captain Twiddlymore,$9.99,2,1
1 records found
```

Here is how you call the awk function within your existing code:

```
#!/bin/bash
  search_book()
{
    awk -F':' -v search="$search" '$1 ~ search || $2 ~ search { i++; printf "%s, %s,$%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 } END { printf "%d records found\n", i }' books.txt
}


read -p "Enter search term: " search

search_book
```